# CodeIgniter remove index.php from href

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, href, codeigniter-url

In a CodeIgniter App

*this link works*

```
<a href="index.php/controller">link</a>
```

*while this one doesn't*

```
<a href="controller">link</a>
```

What's wrong with configuration? What has to be changed in order links work without "index.php/" at the beginning?

This is done without success:

1) added to application/routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'controller';
```

2) added to application/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

3) uncommented in etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Comment: you need to set your `base_url` then use that on every link. What if you go directly to your address bar and type in `localhost/your_app_name/controller/method` ? does it work?

Comment: you need to check that `mod_rewrite` module is enabled in apache. Also you are missing a question mark `?` after the `index.php` in your `RewriteRule`, do it like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should blank the

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in config
         config.php
Then write the following code in .htaccess placed in your project's main directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is closer. But still "The requested URL /Users/olegzhermal/Sites/CI/index.php/controller was not found on this server." (regardless, by the way, of $config['index_page'] = ''. File Controller.php is present in the controllers directory.

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your .htaccess to remove the index.php from the url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Your link should be

```
<a href="/controller">link</a>
```

Config.php should be

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

The rewrite_module should be activated in apache